# Google Apps Script Defined Time-frame for time-driven Triggers Not Working

Tags: triggers, google-apps-script

I am using the functions from the code that I saw here:
http://mashe.hawksey.info/2012/09/google-app-script-scheduling-timed-triggers/
with my added sub-function, as instructed.

```
function scheduledCollection2(){
  var schedule = [];
  // dates/times in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm - timezone matches settings in File > Project properties
  schedule.push({start:"10/25/2014 09:00", end:"12/25/2014 10:00"});
  checkCollect2(schedule);
}

function checkCollect2(schedule){
  var now = new Date();
  for (i in schedule){
    var start = new Date(schedule[i].start);
    var end = new Date(schedule[i].end);
    if (now > start && now < end){
      function sendEmails() {
        var emailAddress = "abc@gmail.com";
        var message = "Hello, this is a test email.";
        var subject = "Sending Recurring Emails";
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The sendEmails function alone works very well. However, when I add it to the rest of the code for some reason it stops working. My aim is to have it work with a time-driven trigger.

Any advice on why it's not working, and how I can get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply build your script slightly differently : (instead of defining a function just execute the code)

```
function checkCollect2(schedule){
  var now = new Date();
  for (i in schedule){
    var start = new Date(schedule[i].start);
    var end = new Date(schedule[i].end);
    if (now > start && now < end){
        var emailAddress = "abc@gmail.com";
        var message = "Hello, this is a test email.";
        var subject = "Sending Recurring Emails";
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense! There's no need for the final definition anyway. Works perfectly now, thank you.